# not found uisprite spriteName in atals

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, ngui

if not found uisprite spriteName in atals,
i want to show another spritename , what can i do?
please give me some advice,Thank you!

```
string aSpriteName = GetIconFromAtlas("item_005");
mTreasure2.transform.FindChild("item/ax/prize1").gameObject.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName =aSpriteName;


string GetIconFromAtlas(string spriteName)
{
    string aSpriteName = spriteName;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aSpriteName)) 
        aSpriteName = "item000";
    return aSpriteName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UISpriteData  aData= this.transform.FindChild("Card1/pic/badge").GetComponent<UISprite>().atlas.GetSprite("item_005");
if(aData == null)
    this.transform.FindChild("item/ax/prize1").GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "item000";
```